# How to remove vim from centos7?

Tags: vim

I want re-install vim 8 from source with python suport on centos 7.

First I want to remove old vim, but when I try use `sudo yum remove vim`  get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, replace
Repository nodesource is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository nodesource-source is listed more than once in the configuration
No Match for argument: vim
No Packages marked for removal
```

I tried remove vim by `rm -rf /usr/local/share/vim`.

But after remove it type command `vim --version` and get:

```
 vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Mar 12 2017 14:25:06)
Included patches: 1-445
Compiled by gefalko@gefalko
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        -toolbar
-clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux -ldl
```

Comment: I removed `/usr/share/vim`,`/usr/local/share/vim` and `/usr/local/bin/vim manualy` manualy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
for file in $(rpm -q --configfiles vim)
do
  echo "  removing $file"
  rm -f $file
done
rpm -e vim
```